# Best App to Track your Mikvah Dates

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, mikvah-ritual-bath

Looking for the best period tracker and mikvah (לוח מקווה) calendar to simplify my mikvah calculations. It should be available on Android phone and able to send reminders and notifications about important days and times.

Comment: I dont think it exists. But this English book is better than any sefer https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/59460 I doubt many rabbis know it as well.

Comment: Thanks @interested I saw Luach Tahara once in a relatives house and have been looking for it since but never found it. Thanks so much for posting the link.

Comment: @Eliyahu Tell us all what you think about it. Are vestos that simple like everyone here thinks and any new young couple can know it.

Comment: @interested Obviously Vestos aren't that complicated and every young couple can do it. But with all of the stresses of life it's easy to make a mistake. I personally highly recommend using apps for a few reasons 1- You get notifications so you don't forgot that its the day of the Vest (that has happened to me before and I'm sure has happened to most people who have been married for a while). 2- Vestos Kavuah are complicated and you may miss it if it happens. I still recommend having a paper back-up for Shabbos and just in case something goes wrong and your info gets lost.

Comment: @Eliyahu "Obviously Vestos aren't that complicated and every young couple can do it." Why is that obvious? The simple cases are indeed simple but the complicated cases are hard to notice.

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant the three standard - Chodesh, Onah Beinonis, and Haflaga. I mentioned that Vestos Kavuah are complicated in point #2.

Comment: @Eliyahu if you agree most couples aren't set up to catch the complicated situations, then what is the point of your comment? If I don't know when I need help then either I ask every time or perforce make mistakes.

Comment: I was asked a question by @interested so I answered it. As he said, most people refer to calculating Vestos as not that difficult. I explained that that's specifically the 3 basic ones. But its still worth ahving the app for the reasons I outlined. I do agree with the point you made that you have to be sure that you app matches your Minhagim. I once downloaded a Chabad app by mistake and was immensely confused how the app was so far off on the Haflaga.

Comment: @Eliyahu All I can say is that you havent read yet that booklet.

Comment: @interested No. Not yet (other than flipping through it a bit at a relative's house).

Answer (score 4):

https://www.mymikvahcalendar.org

They have an app for both iOS and android.
It follows the chabad minhagim.
Even with the app it doesn’t do absolutely everything. You can call them up and ask them for a tutorial and what you need to be aware of using the app.
First few months are totally free. After that the basic counter is free but the advanced kevuos and some other stuff cost 18$ a year. (Which will also give you a discount on buying the physical calendar (another 18$))
The associated website is https://www.mikvah.org

I think that mikvahcalendar.com is the same people just marketed to other minhagim but I can’t say for sure. Having never used either one but know many people who do use the chabad one I can only speak for that. But if it’s the same it should be pretty good.

Comment: Note, chabad minhagim differ from most other people's in certain details of calculating vestot (particularly haflaga) so be very very very careful about using an app instead of speaking to your rabbi.

Answer (score 2):

There's an app called Luach. It's free on the [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luachandroid&hl=en_US&gl=US) and [iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/luach/id1259500420) app stores. It provides calculations, reminders, the works. Make sure to double check all calculations, but it's a good starting point.